# Why we need CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER in windows

Tags: php, linux, curl, server, vps

I'm going to explain a little bit about my script so you can understand my question.

Basically i did a script that checks the SOCKS5 if it is `live` or `dead`.

When i tested my script on `Linux VPS` and `iMac` it was working perfectly, however when i tested it on Windows with `wampserver` it did not work until i added this line to `cURL` :

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Can anyone explain to me why do i need this line in Windows and i don't need it on the Linux server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cURL man page on [SSL Certificates](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) describes the process for ***Certificate Verification*** when connecting to SSL/TLS secured hosts.

The reason you are needing to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` on Windows is because the CA bundle it uses to verify the certificates is missing (or there is no default path compiled into cURL so you need to explicitly define it).

You can configure it in `php.ini` using the [curl.cainfo](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.configuration.php#ini.curl.cainfo) directive, or specify it at runtime using:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAFILE, 'C:/path/to/ca-bundle.crt');
```

If you don't have a copy, grab a recent one [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

While disabling peer verification is a workaround, this can be unsafe because you're disabling the very check that ensures you are securely communicating with the site you think you are.

Anyone can generate a self signed certificate to impersonate a domain, but browsers or clients (like cURL) will fail if the certificate can't be verified unless you ignore or bypass this check (i.e. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false).

Comment: Can you help me with this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943476/login-to-ws1-using-curl   and please can you suggest for me a place where i can master the curl, because really I'm facing problem with :(

Answer (score 0):

Drew010's answer is correct. I'd just add that there problem you're experiencing isn't so much a Windows v Linux issue as much as it is that the two environments differ. You could encounter the same difference between two Linux environments (where I encountered this exact issue), with the roles reversed (works in Windows but not in Linux), etc.