# Login to WS1 using curl

Tags: php, http, curl, libcurl, php-curl

I'm trying to login into ws1.com using curl, however whenever i put the POST to true I'm getting error: Bad Request, this is the code that i tried:

```
<?php
$LOGINURL = "https://secure2.ws1.com/login";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "_csrf=QTRvNkJKaUoWBFYDBHkLDHFkP0MdMhAPOUZCASR9Xh4ZRDx7BC8LGA%3D%3D&LoginForm%5Bemail%5D=naczzalid%40hotmail.com&LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=csc1233&LoginForm%5BrememberMe%5D=0&login-button=");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
echo $result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Anyone please can explain to me what is the problem in this so i can learn how to do it?

Comment: Could be giving a bad request if you POST to that page with no data.  Maybe if the csrf token is missing they issue a bad request as well.  Make sure you are submitting all the proper form fields and anything else their login page requires.

Comment: yes I'm sure that i submitted everything, however when i put post = 1 i get this error

Comment: You don't put any of the post fields with example data so its hard to tell.  That is the correct URL to post to though.  Maybe it needs a referer too.  And you are sending the correct `_csrf` post field value?

Comment: i think so, i just updated the code to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested some things with this form and if the `csrf` code is incorrect, then it gives a bad request.

The csrf value changes for every request and is tied to your cookies.  So you need to fetch the login page first and extract the correct csrf code before submitting.

Working code:

```
<?php
$LOGINURL = "https://secure2.ws1.com/login";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

// extract csrf token
preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="([^"]+)">/i', $result, $csrf);
$csrf = $csrf[1];
$csrf = urlencode($csrf);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "_csrf={$csrf}&LoginForm%5Bemail%5D=naczzalid%40hotmail.com&LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=csc1233&LoginForm%5BrememberMe%5D=0&login-button=");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thank you very much, buy why sometimes you send header and refere and sometimes no? when so we need them