# php OAuthException after url changes

Tags: php, oauth

I have a php site (Site A) that users are logged into by clicking a link on a different site (Site B) and it works great!

Recently Site B changed their domain name. After making the correct name changes on Site A, I am getting the following error message:

```
OAuthException Object ( [message:protected] => making the request failed (Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates) [string:Exception:private] => exception 'OAuthException' with message 'making the request failed (Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates)'
```

The line that is causing this error is $oauth->fetch("$api_url");

After forwarding this error to our provider, they simply said it was not an issue on there end.

cUrl enabled: version 7.46.0
Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2
php 5.6.18

Comment: Either the web site has an invalid certificate or you have incomplete CA certificates on your server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we need CURLOPT\_SSL\_VERIFYPEER in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795717/why-we-need-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-in-windows)