# Web Crawling a website returns empty (using preg_match_all)

Tags: php, web-crawler

I m trying to pull all the queries listed in this [page](http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1) using a webcrawler (code below). But it seems like I have missed something.

My Code goes as:

```
<?php
    function getSslPage($url){
                    
       $ch = curl_init();      
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,   "cookie.txt");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Chrome/36.0.1985.125");
           $login = curl_exec($ch);
           return $login;
   }
                        
       $milesfeed  = getSslPage('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1'); 
       preg_match_all('/<td class="FootNotes2">(.*?)<\/td>/s',$milesfeed,$links);
                        
       $milesfeed_links=[]; 
       $milesfeed_text=[]; 
                        
       $fourth="abc";
       $third="abc";
   //$third="https://onemileatatime";
       foreach($links[1] as $miles){
                            
       $milesfeed_text[] = strip_tags($miles);
       preg_match_all('/<a target="_top" class="Links2" href="(.*?)">/s', $miles, $link);
       $milesfeed_links[] = strip_tags($link[1][0]); 
       $first=explode("://",$link[1][0]);
       $second=explode(".",$first[1]);
       //print_r($second);
                            
       if($second[0]!=$third || $third=="abc"){
           if($second[0]=="www"){
                 echo "<h3>".ucfirst($second[1])."</h3>";
           }else{
                 echo "<h3>".ucfirst($second[0])."</h3>";
           }
       }
        echo '<a href="'.$link[1][0].'" target="_blank">'.wordwrap(strip_tags($miles),30).'</a><br><br>';
           $third=$second[0]; 
      }
?>
```

I spent 4 hours straight trying to figure it out by myself. Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does your curl_exec returns the html? Or is that one empty to

Comment: Just an aside - worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795717/why-we-need-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-in-windows for a general idea about using `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false`

Answer (score 1):

The class `class="FootNotes2"` is not in the `tr` but in the `td` maybe that will change your result

Edit:

Your Rexeg is not right in this situation. You search for `<td class="FootNotes2"` but between `<td` and the `class="FootNotes2"` you also have other attributes

Change your regex to `<td .*? class="FootNotes2">(.*?)<\/td>` will maybe help you

You can use https://regex101.com/ to test. I dropped the curl response in it and changed your regex to test it there

**EDIT again:**

I toke a better look at your code and looked at the website you try to scrape.
But you have way to many errors in your code. In your loop you asume value exist without checking then, you try to rexeg values and paterns that does not exist in the page you try to scrape. Copy the html of that page and study it and test it in a regex tester, also var_dump your results to what you get back from your functions and write checks to make sure the data exist you whant to work with. Do this step by step and you will get your result.

Comment: Unfortunately NO, it didn't. But thanks for brining it up.

Comment: You also have a typo in `milesfeed_links=[]; ` You mis the $ sign

Comment: @HarishK I updated my answer, I noticed also a typo in your rexeg

Comment: Did what you mentioned. No luck yet. `preg_match_all('<td .*? class="FootNotes2">(.*?)<\/td>',$milesfeed,$links);` Thanks for the time.

Comment: Thats because you also need to change your second rexeg funtion. I used `/<td .* class="FootNotes2">(.*?)<\/td>/` and got 90 results in my `$links[1]`

Comment: Bro i changed the second one to `preg_match_all('<a .*? class="Links2">(.*?)<\/a>', $miles, $link);` yet I still black. can you post your answer above..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function con(){
            $q=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','usmle');
            return $q;
    }
    function addquery($a,$b,$c,$d){
            $a=mysqli_real_escape_string(con(),$a);
            $b=mysqli_real_escape_string(con(),$b);
            $c=mysqli_real_escape_string(con(),$c);
            $d=mysqli_real_escape_string(con(),$d);
            mysqli_query(con(),"insert into query(Query,QueryBy,QueryLink,Date)values('$a','$b','$c','$d')");
    }
    function addreply($a,$b){
        $a=mysqli_real_escape_string(con(),$a);
        $b=mysqli_real_escape_string(con(),$b);
        mysqli_query(con(),"insert into replies(QueryID,Reply)values($a,'$b')");
    }
    
    function lastID(){
        $q=mysqli_query(con(),"select MAX(QueryID) as LastID from query LIMIT 1");
        return $q;
    }
    function getSslPage($url){

        $ch = curl_init();      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,   "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Chrome/36.0.1985.125");
        $login = curl_exec($ch);
        return $login;
    }
    function cleannr($str)
{
//     $str = str_replace("£", "", $str);
    $str = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\n", "\r"), ',', $str);
    $str = str_replace("\n" , "" , $str);
    $str = trim(strip_tags($str));
    return str_replace("," , " " , $str);
}
$set=0;
    $athomepage  = getSslPage('http://www.usmleforum.com/forum/index.php?forum=1&Page=1'); 
    preg_match_all('/<td width="64%" height="25" class="FootNotes2"><a href="(.*?)" target="_top" class="Links2">(.*?)<\/a>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$athomepage,$pages);
    
                /*  $count = $pages[2][0];
                 $total_pages = 1;
                
                 if($count > 0){
                     $pages = $pages[0][$count-1];
                     $total_pages = strip_tags($pages);
                
                 } */
                 // echo $total_pages;
                 // die;
            // echo "<pre>".print_r($listres,true)."</pre>";
                // die;
                foreach($pages[1] as $links){
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                    $set++;
                    echo 'Query No.'.$set.'<br />'; 
                    //echo "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/controller/exposeNavigation/goToExpose.go?exposeId=".$links."<br>";
                     //die;
                     $link="http://www.usmleforum.com".$links;
                     $ipage=getSslPage("http://www.usmleforum.com".$links."");
                     preg_match_all('/<td width="95%" valign="top" colspan="2" class="FormText2">(.*?)<\/td>/s',$ipage,$query);
                     preg_match_all('/<td width="97%" colspan="2" valign="top" class="FootNotes2">(.*?)<\/td>/s',$ipage,$by);
                    
                     $explodation=explode("-",$by[1][0]);
                    $date=$explodation[1];
                    $name=$explodation[0];
                    $actualquery=cleannr($query[1][0]);
                    echo '<h2>Query : </h2><br />';
                    echo 'Query : '.$actualquery.'<br />'; 
                    echo 'Query By : '.$name.'<br />'; 
                    echo 'Link : '.$link.'<br />'; 
                    echo 'Date : '.$date.'<br />'; 
                    
                    addquery($actualquery,$name,$link,$date);
                    
                    $id=lastID();
                    foreach($id as $ids){
                        $lastID=$ids["LastID"];
                    } 
                echo '<h2>Replies : </h2><br />';
                for($i=1;$i<count($query[1]);$i++){
                    if($query[1][$i]!=""){
                        $replyquery=cleannr($query[1][$i]);
                        
                        echo 'Reply : '.$replyquery.'<br />';                   
                        addreply($lastID,$replyquery);
                    }
                }
                
                     
                }
                    echo "<center><h2>Scraping Done</h2></center>";
?>
```

Nailed it.